# Is it possible to host web service in C++ metro style app without loading the CLR?

Tags: c++, web-services, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am wondering whether it is possible to create a C++ metro style app which hosts a web service (think of plain old `System.Web.Services.WebService`) without loading the CLR.

I heard that there are alternatives build specially for metro style apps, but I couldn't find anything that can answer my question. Is WWSAPI such an option? Are there other options?

Any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT: It seems that WWSAPI cannot be used because `WsCreateServiceHost` and `WsOpenServiceHost` are not available for metro style apps.